# Using getBestDateTimePattern()

Tags: android

According to the news about [Android 4.3](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/jelly-bean.html?43)

> To assist you with managing date formatting across locales, Android
>   4.3 includes a new **getBestDateTimePattern()** method that automatically generates the best possible localized form of a Unicode UTS date for a
>   locale that you specify. It’s a convenient way to provide a more
>   localized experience for your users.

How do I use this method? I could not find it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateFormat.html#getBestDateTimePattern%28java.util.Locale%20java.lang.String%29):

> **public static String getBestDateTimePattern (Locale locale, String skeleton)**
>
> *Added in API level 18*
>
> Returns the best possible localized form of the given skeleton for the given locale. A skeleton is similar to, and uses the same format characters as, a Unicode UTS #35 pattern.
>
> One difference is that order is irrelevant. For example, "MMMMd" will return "MMMM d" in the en_US locale, but "d. MMMM" in the de_CH locale.
>
> Note also in that second example that the necessary punctuation for German was added. For the same input in es_ES, we'd have even more extra text: "d 'de' MMMM".
>
> This method will automatically correct for grammatical necessity. Given the same "MMMMd" input, this method will return "d LLLL" in the fa_IR locale, where stand-alone months are necessary. Lengths are preserved where meaningful, so "Md" would give a different result to "MMMd", say, except in a locale such as ja_JP where there is only one length of month.
>
> This method will only return patterns that are in CLDR, and is useful whenever you know what elements you want in your format string but don't want to make your code specific to any one locale.
>
> **Parameters**
>
> *locale*:  the locale into which the skeleton should be localized
>
> *skeleton*:    a skeleton as described above
>
> **Returns**
>
> a string pattern suitable for use with SimpleDateFormat.

Answer (score 6):

7½ years later, here's an answer with a practical example! ;-)

```
Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();
String skeleton = DateFormat.getBestDateTimePattern(locale, "MMMM d, YYYY");
```

Then, using java.time:

```
Instant.now().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(skeleton));
```

Or using legacy classes:

```
Date now = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
SimpleDateFormat dateTimeFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(skeleton, locale);
dateTimeFormatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
dateTimeFormatter.applyLocalizedPattern(skeleton);
dateTimeFormatter.format(now);
```

Comment: https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Comment: Thank you, Pat! I had been using getBestDateTimePattern with SimpleDateFormat, but was looking for how to use the same for formatting a LocalDate. Perfect answer (covering both usage scenarios)!